# Can I print lines randomly from a csv in Python?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I'm trying print lines randomly from a csv.

Lets say the csv has the below 10 lines -

```
1,One
2,Two
3,Three
4,Four
5,Five
6,Six
7,Seven
8,Eight
9,Nine
10,Ten
```

If I write a code like below, it prints each line as a list in the same order as present in the CSV

```
import csv

with open("MyCSV.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row_num, row in enumerate(reader):
        print(row)
```

Instead, I'd like it to be random.

Its just a print for now. I'll later pass each line as a List to a Function.

Comment: save into a list, shuffle it and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can define a list, append all elements of csv file into it, then shuffle it and print them, assume that the name of this list is `temp`

```
 import csv
 import random
 temp = []

 with open("your csv file.csv") as file:
 reader = csv.reader(file)
 for row_num, row in enumerate(reader):
     temp.append(row)

 random.shuffle(temp)

 for i in range(len(temp)):
     print(temp[i])
```

Comment: Just want to point out that using temporary lists is not pythonic. Comprehensions (extended with generators) are always preferred. Also, you drop the row numbers, so why bother calling `enumerate`?

Comment: @dijksterhuis that's what OP prints, we are supposed to answer in the way OP wants

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import random
csv_elems = []

with open("MyCSV.csv") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row_num, row in enumerate(reader):
    csv_elems.append(row)

random.shuffle(csv_elems)
print(csv_elems[0])
```

As you can see I'm just printing the first elem, you can iterate over the list, keep shuffling & print

Comment: one shuffling  is enough if OP does not want to get the same line some times

Comment: missing indentation after `with` statement

Comment: Thank you.
I just added - 
```
for a in csv_elems:
    print(a)
```
and thats what I'm expecting

Comment: As per another answer, using temporary lists is not pythonic. Comprehensions are preferred unless it is absolutely necessary. Also you’re dropping the row numbers. So the `enumerate` call isn’t doing anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You can reuse the `lines` list in your code as it is shuffled.

```
import random

with open("tmp.csv", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

random.shuffle(lines)
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why better don't you use pandas to handle csv?

`import pandas as pd`

`data = pd.read_csv("MyCSV.csv")`

And to get the samples you are looking for just write:

`data.sample() # print one sample`
`data.sample(5) # to write 5 samples`

Also if you want to pass each line to a function.
`data_after_function = data.appy(function_name)`
and inside the function you can cast the line into a list with `list()`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to do:

1. Store CSV into a sequence of some sort
2. Get the data randomly

For 1, it’s probably best to use some form of sequence comprehension (I’ve gone for nested tuple in a list as it seems you want the row numbers and we can’t use dictionaries for shuffle).

We can use the `random` module for number 2.

```
import random
import csv

with open("MyCSV.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    my_csv = [(row_num, row) for row_num, row in enumerate(reader)]

# get only 1 item from the list at random
random_row = random.choice(my_csv)

# randomise the order of all the rows
shuffled_csv = random.shuffle(my_csv)
```